# Blazor audio play from files within a directory

Tags: c#, html, blazor

With Blazor I'm trying to list audio files from a directory on to a web browser, to then select an audio file and play it.

I've loaded the audio files from the directory to the web page, but I'm having trouble with choosing a file on the page and then playing the audio.
The code:
`

```
<div class ="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="loadMidiFiles">Load files</button>
        <hr />
        <h2>File List</h2>
        <hr />
        @if(filesList != null && filesList.Count > 0)
        {
            int auF = 0;
            @foreach (string file in filesList)
            {
                auF++;
                <br />
                <span>@auF.</span>
                <span @onclick="@(e=>readFile(file))" style="cursor:pointer;
                      text-decoration:underline;color:blue;">@file</span>
            }
        }
    </div>    
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <h3>Title: @midName</h3>
        <audio controls="controls"> 
            <source src="@mid" type="audio/mp3">
            
        </audio>
    </div>
</div> 

@code{
    string mid = "";
    string midName= "N/A";
    List<string> filesList = new List<string>();
    string path = $"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}{@"\wwwroot\uploadedFile"}";

    public void loadMidiFiles()
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            filesList.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
        }
    }

    public void readFile(string fileName)
    {
        midName = fileName.Split('.')[0];
        mid = "wwwroot/uploadedFile/" + fileName;
    }
}
```

`

Here are pictures of the page.

Before loading files:
[image]

Files are loaded:
[image]

File is chosen
[image]

Edit: deleted `<source src="uploadedFile\sample-9s.mp3">` from within the audio tags, and replaced it with `<source src="@mid" type="audio/mp3">`, as I want all the files playable.

Answer (score 0):

Should the mid field be used in the source src attribute?

Comment: I thought it would make the the files from the directory playable, but I'm not sure if it was the right approach, or if it can be done in a different fashion.